# How to uninstall the JDK after deleting its files?

Tags: java, windows

I wanted to install the JDK, but when I try to, it says:

> This software has already been installed on your computer.
>   Would you like to reinstall it?

I press yes.

> Preparing to remove...

Then after that it says...

> Please wait while Windows configures Java SE Development Kit 7 update 45

After that I get an error:

```
Error 1316.A network error occurred while attempting to read from the file C:\Windows\Installer\jdk1.7.0_45.msi
```

But the `C:\Windows\Installer` directory doesn’t exist! :(

I've narrowed it down to me deleting the files for the JDK (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk`) and apparently those files have a file that the Java installer needs to uninstall it. Please tell me how to thoroughly delete all the files for the JDK so I can install it again! Or another way!

Comment: This isn't a programming issue, I'm afraid. :(

Comment: One way would be to install it on a different machine in the same path, copy over the files and then uninstall again.

Comment: Remove the JDK from your system `path`.

Comment: I don't have the JDK in my path ):

Comment: Then there's probably something hiding in your registry.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the entire C:/Program Files/Java directory, download Java SE 7u45 JDK from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

and run it to install. Should work. The download is the JRE and JDK in one, so you don't have to install the jre seperatly.

Comment: Hm... will deleting the all the java files make me unable to run java programs like IE?

Comment: Just download the jdk first before removing the java dir. You said you deleted the files already and here you are anyway. And no, IE is not a java program.

Comment: I deleted the java directory and ran the installer, and i get the same errors ):

Comment: Did you try a reboot? Also check if it's still listed in software. http://www.java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_java.xml

Comment: I did reboot and tried uninstalling again, didn't work. And it is listed in software. By the way when I try to uninstall it using "Uninstall Programs" in control panel, it gives me the same error as the installer did.

Comment: Are the files still in the waste-bin? If so, undelete them and try uninstall again. I don't know anything else that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure you have enabled invisible directorys. *C:\Windows\Installer* is an invisible directory. 
You could copy/paste it in your address box.

The solution for you should be the following.

1. Open the registry editor (regedit.exe)
2. Go to
   *HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products*
3. Search for Java Development Kit.
4. Get MSIZap! Can be found here http://nerdoftherings.net/wp/?p=66
5. Get the *ProductCode* out of the **Transforms** Value. The *ProductCode* starts and ends with {}. I  But be careful you need the complete product code!
6. Open a command line an run MSIZap with the following paratemers:

   *MsiZap.exe GPSTW! {your-product-code}*
7. Try to install the new JDK.